# Why is my program generating the correct output for sum of all prime numbers under 100, but not under 1 million?

Tags: java, primes

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<Integer.parseInt(args[0]); i++)
    {
        if(i != 1 && i%2 != 0 && i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0 && i%7 != 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;          
        }
        if(i==2 || i==3 || i==5 || i==7)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Whenever I plug in 100, it generates 1060, which is correct. However, it generates the incorrect number for 1,000,000 (114,285,285,737).

It's generating correctly for all values under 100, haven't tried anything else. I'm not ONLY checking for 100.

Comment: This isn't a valid way to find all prime numbers - it will accept many numbers which are *not* prime.

Comment: What is the program supposed to compute? Perhaps you should include more prime numbers in your if-statements than just 1, 2, 3, 5 and 7 to get the answer correctly for higher numbers.

Comment: I don't see how above program check for prime numbers

Comment: Why does it work up to 100 then?

Comment: @Ghostkeeper: Oh God... You are kidding, right?

Comment: @user2770254: There are lots of programs whose output is 1060.  They are not all valid prime-summers.

Comment: It's working when I put in 12, 13, 14, 15, anything up to 100. I'm not JUST checking 100. Give me some benefit of the doubt, please.

Comment: The majority of numbers that aren't prime are divisible by those numbers, hence it appears to work, but the only actual test is to test if its exactly divisible by **every** prime up to the square root of the number being tested

Comment: You need a better definition of primeness in your code. The definition of a prime number is not "any number not divisible by 2, 3, 5 or 7." If you want to use this sort of approach, you should understand that it will fail for large-enough numbers (numbers greater than the square of the largest prime you hard-code in). At the very least, you should check that your inputs are smaller than these too-large numbers, and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if they are. Or better yet, improve the primeness definition.

Comment: Just so I understand your way of thinking;  why do you think that 7 is the last prime that is important for your test, why not 5 or 11?

Comment: It was a lapse of judgement/logic. Bad day, I guess. Thanks @yshavit for being helpful and not condescending. Also, I kind of based my logic off of a Sieve of Eratosthenes gif which ended at 120. Shows why mine fails at 121. [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_animation.gif)

Comment: Tests show that this algorithm matches the requirement up to `n = 122`, at which point it incorrectly returns `1714` where the correct sum should be `1593`. Perhaps this is therefore a MathOverflow question.

Comment: because `100 < 11^2 < 1000000`.

Comment: -1 Please put in some minimal effort to understand and debug your problems before asking on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You're right! Sorry about that. I'll keep that in mind before posting again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sum all the prime numbers below a certain number.   The problem is that your definition of "prime number" is "the numbers 2,3,5,7 and all numbers which cannot be divided with 2,3,5 or 7 without a remainder" which is not correct.

The correct definition of prime number is "A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself." (wikipedia).  Hence this needs to be your test instead of your current test.

If all numbers between 1 and the number itself (both excluded) give a remainder with division you have a prime.

If you change your program to use this definition instead, you should get the correct result.

(and for speed you can consider if you *really* have to test *all* the numbers or if you can get the same result by checking only some of them)

(also the reason why it works up to 100 is because you only need to test for the primes less than the square root (here 10) of the number and those are 2, 3, 5, and 7 for 100 which is exactly what your program does).

Answer (score 3):

Your method involves checking all the primes from 1 to the square-root of your target to see if they are factors of each number in your target range.

For a target of 100, that means looking at each number between 1 and 100 to see if it is divisible by a prime in the range 1 to 10 (2, 3, 5 & 7). As you have discovered, this works.

For 1,000,000 you need to check all the primes between 1 and 1000, to see if they're factors of each number between 1 and 1,000,000. Your code is still only checking the primes between 1 and 10.

To make your code work, extend your list to include all the primes between 1 and 1000 - there are 168 of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The smallest prime number that your problem will fail on is 11. Know that 11 is a prime number. The serie goes on: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ...

Comment: My program doesn't fail at 11. If I give an input of 12 (sum all primes under 12) it generates 28 which is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11. This is not incorrect.

Comment: You don't understand... How shall I explain? Try with 11*11.

Comment: Would I need to completely rethink my approach to fix this?

Comment: @user In other words, your program believes 121 is prime,  but it's not because it's exactly divisble by 11 (don't just add 11 to your list, there are an infinite number of primes)

Comment: The way of trying to determine wether a number is a prime number was good. Except you implemented it wrong. You only check for divisors 2, 3, 5 and 7. You need to check all the higher divisors as well. Test this in a for loop.

Comment: @user yes, you need to write a function that checks if a number is prime, this function will (in the simplest mode) check if the test number is exactly divisble by every number up to the square root of the test number (only testimg for primes below this value is strictly nessissary and wpuld be a good improvement)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this condition:

```
if(i != 1 && i%2 != 0 && i%3 != 0 && i%5 != 0 && i%7 != 0)
```

As others have stated, that is not a valid way to check if a number is prime.  The reason your program *appears* to work is because, for example, 209 is not divisible by 2, 3, 5, or 7, but 209 is 11 * 19, which is **not** prime.